# bower private git dependency without user@hostname

Tags: git, bower, gitblit

I've specified one of our firm's private Gitblit git repos in another project's bower.json file like so.

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-api": "git+ssh://user@hostname:port/my-api.git#develop"
}
```

There are several people on the project and I want to avoid each person having to specify their own user@hostname in the dependency url.

Is there a way to do this with our existing ssh keys?  In case it's relevant, Gitblit is interfaced with Gerrit and Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Gitblit currently **requires** the username in the SSH url.  This was implemented for server performance.  There is an open request to change this behavior to allow use of something like `git@hostname:port` and brute-force-validate the incoming SSH key against every stored SSH key.  For now you are stuck, although you could switch to http/https but then you end up with password prompts.

Comment: Thanks James.  Always good to talk to the organ grinder :)

I've looked into passing process.env variables as well but it seems that's not possible.  Are there any work-arounds until the request you describe is implemented?